# Conditional formatting for whole rows based on first cells if duplicated

Tags: excel

Excel allows to do the duplicated values conditional formatting quite easily. However, the result shows for cells rather entire rows or columns.

I would like to have a conditional formatting that work for entire rows based the condition on the first cells.

For example,
If columns A have 3 repeated columns on A2, A3, A4, then it nightlights row 2, 3, and 4 instead of just cell A2, A3, A4?

Can it be doable without Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Instead of highlighting Columns, Highlight the rows and then use a formula to find duplicates.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I would like to extend the problem a little, for example, if there are 4 "3"s, and another "5" - can they have different color?  I need at least 2 alternative colors

Comment: Yes it is possbile but then you will have to use multiple conditional formats :) For example `=AND(COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1,$A1=3)` for `3` and `=AND(COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1,$A1=5)` for `5`

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out.  The problem I encounter is that I would to distinct between two similar groups that closed to each others (in this example, group 1s versus 2s versus 5. Something like: http://i50.tinypic.com/2d8qrf8.png  This is for readability.